# SMTP daemon on alternate port to capture all messages to single Dovecot mailbox

Tags: postfix, smtp, dovecot

There's several answers on here about how to configure postfix to redirect all messages to a single mailbox, for development/testing of mail scripts.

I'm looking for a variation on this where I open an alternate port on an existing mail server, and I want all SMTP messages delivered to that port to get dumped into a mailbox (Dovecot, via local delivery) on that same server.

My problem is that smtpd shares the configuration in main.cf, and I don't see a way to run a second copy of smtpd without configuring an entire separate postfix environment.  I'm looking for a simpler solution.

The `smtp-sink` program is *almost* exactly what I want.  It writes each message to a new file, but I would additionally like them pushed over local delivery to Dovecot where my mail client can conveniently see them.

Can anyone recommend a simple way to make this happen?  I'll even accept a perl script that listen/reads SMTP and writes LMTP.

Comment: What problem is this meant to solve? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912

Comment: For delivery, do you want use [dovecot LMTP](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LMTP) or [postfix local](http://www.postfix.org/local.8.html) service?

Comment: I want to solve the problem of redirecting email I generate from dev machines to a mailbox where I can quickly view the email (complete with real-world to/from/cc headers) in a standard mail client, but without a bunch of infrastructure that I have to maintain.  I want to be able to direct outbound SMTP of my dev projects to this destination with minimal hassle.  And I want minimal complexity so it doesn't explode on me by accident.

Comment: @masegaloeh - I have postfix configured with ```local_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp```.  I'm not sure if that bypasses local, or is a setting used *by* local.  If it is used *by* local then an answer with postfix local would be preferred, because it's one less duplicated configuration setting.

Comment: If you configure `smtp-sink` to write messages to the user/Maildir/new/ directory inside the dovecot storage then they should appear in your inbox. Just make sure they're written with the right owner/group.

Comment: @wurtel - I'm using dbox mail storage, but that's such a simple solution I'm tempted to go back to Maildir

Comment: So I tried smtp-sink into Maildir but it doesn't quite work, because Dovecot is so fast it can can catch a large email when it is half-written and then the IMAP client caches half of it, and I'm not having any luck getting Thunderbird to re-fetch the message.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` on secondary port (for example port 9925) so it REDIRECT email to your selected mailbox (for example dumpbin@example.com).

The entry of master.cf

```
9925      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=check_recipient_access,pcre:/etc/postfix/x.pcre,reject_unauth_destination
```

File `/etc/postfix/x.pcre`

```
/.*/    REDIRECT dumpbin@example.com
```

With this setup, every email coming to this port will match PCRE pattern on `/etc/postfix/x.pcre`, therefore postfix will REDIRECT it to dumpbin@example.com.

Your last task is ensure that dumpbin@example.com was delivered via dovecot LMTP.

Comment: This doesn't quite work...  I'm running Postfix 3.0.1, and when I try this I get "Relay Access Denied".  I tried removing the options that deny relaying but it gives me ```fatal: in parameter smtpd_relay_restrictions or smtpd_recipient_restrictions, specify at least one working instance of: reject_unauth_destination, defer_unauth_destination, reject, defer, defer_if_permit or check_relay_domains```.  I tried overriding the virtual_alias_maps but it doesn't seem to take effect. Looks like rewriting happens from a separate service, before the smtp relay checks occur.

Comment: Woops, forgot to add that mandatory parameter... See the edit